# How to return to shell prompt in xterm linux?

Tags: linux, shell, console, command-line

When I do this:

```
[myuser@myserver ~]$ find . -type f -name "*Myfile* -name "*20130*"
>
```

It enters ">" mode, and I can't exit it. How do I retun to shell prompt?

Comment: You are missing a closing quote at the end of the first pattern.

Comment: you forgot a `"` after `"*Myfile*`

Comment: Why did it get negative votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unmatched `"`

```
find . -type f -name "*Myfile* -name "*20130*"
                     ^        ^
```

You should be able to `Ctr-C` your way out if it.